# Unable to extract the serial execution result through the append function

Tags: python

I write a python program
Save the data in the list through the append function
I hope the effect that can be achieved is

```py
Please enter the student's grade: 90
Please enter the student's grade: 100
Please enter the student's grade: 33
Please enter the student's grade: 34
Please enter the student's grade: 80
Please enter the student's grade: 58
Please enter the student's grade: -1
6 students in total
The class total score: 395 points，average score: 65.83 points
```

After entering -1, the loop stops looping and displays the print result
But my python program has been unable to achieve this effect
Execution error keeps appearing
I hope you can provide guidance and assistance
Thank you everyone
My code:

````py
stu=list()
score=int(input("Please enter the student's score:"))
while -1!=score:
     stu.append(score)
     score=int(input("Please enter the student's score:"))
sum=0
sum+=score
stu.count("Please enter the student's grade:")
print("Total",str(sum),"students")
sums=(sum*2)/10
print("Class total score",str(sum),", average score:",str(sums),"points")
    ```
````

Comment: I think you're confusing `stu` and `score`.  `stu` is the list, `score` is a single input, but you're doing `for scs in score`.

Comment: I understand.
Thank you for your remind.

Comment: @allencrismy Do you got your answer?

Comment: not yet.
The result of python program execution is not the result I need

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this. Never use variable names like `sum`, `int` etc as they are in-built keywords for python functions.

```
stu = list()
sum_total = 0

while True:
     score=int(input("Please enter the student's score :"))
     if score == -1:
         break
     stu.append(score)
     sum_total += score


#stu.count("Please enter the student's grade :")
print("Total", len(stu),"students")
sum_average = (sum_total * 2) / 10
print("Class total score", sum_total,", average score:", sum_average, "points")

Please enter the student's score :65
Please enter the student's score :45
Please enter the student's score :65
Please enter the student's score :45
Please enter the student's score :-1
Total 4 students
Class total score 220 , average score: 44.0 points
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the list of scores in a loop, and then use `sum` and `mean` to get the total and average of the list:

```
from statistics import mean

scores = []
while True:
    scores.append(int(input("Please enter the student's grade: ")))
    if scores[-1] < 0:
        scores.pop()
        break

print(f"Total: {len(scores)} students")
print(f"Class total score: {sum(scores)} average score: {mean(scores)}")
```

```
Please enter the student's grade: 10
Please enter the student's grade: 20
Please enter the student's grade: 30
Please enter the student's grade: -1
Total: 3 students
Class total score: 60 average score: 20
```